# Highlight Part of Image Icon on JLabel in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, jlabel

I have an image of a map. When the user clicks a button, I want to put a red square box as a highlight on a certain location of the map like this:

[image]

How do I highlight a portion like this? 
Currently, I am achieving this by creating a new image which has this area highlight and loading that image when the user clicks on the button. However in this case I'll have to develop 66 images and load one for each button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the `JLabel` to do custom painting.

You would keep an `ArrayList` of `Rectangles` that you want to paint. When you click a button you add a `Rectangle` to the `ArrayList`. Then in the `paintComponent(...)` method you iterate through the `ArrayList` to paint each `Rectangle`.

So the basic changes to the extend the `JLabel` would be:

```
private ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

...

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (Rectangle r: rectangles)
    {
        g.setColor( Color.RED );
        g.drawRect(...);
    }
}

public void addRectangle(Rectangle r)
{
    rectangles.add( r );
}
```

For a working example of this approach check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

Another option might be to use a JLayer to paint the Rectangles on the JLabel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Decorate Component With the JLayer Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html#drawing) for some working examples.

Either way you need to do custom painting. Try both approaches to see which you prefer.

Comment: if I zoom in on the JLabel's Icon, will these rectangles adjust their position with it or will they be on the same position they were before?

Comment: Your question was about adding rectangles to an image. Your question has been answered so don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer  I didn't.